# ROS2 Topics Don't Seen at Another PC

Tags: ros2

I can't see the topics running on other computers. I can only see the topics running on my computer. Topics running on my own computer cannot be seen on other computers. For example: I run "ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker" and while my own computer can see the /chatter topic, another computer cannot see this topic. On the other hand I can't see any topic that the other computer is running.

Same Network and Same ROS_DOMAIN_ID

Expected behavior: Both computers can see each other's topics

Comment: can you ping from the other computers to yours, and vice-versa?

Comment: I can send ping vice-versa